# Suppose $f:A\rightarrow B$ Will it always be true that $f^{-1}(Y \texttt{\\}Z)=f^{-1}(Y) \texttt{\\} f^{-1}(Z)$ $?$ $ Proof?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We don't know whether this is true or false. So i wrote a proof of this claim and figured that it's actually correct. However i'm not sure if my proof is correct. Could someone check it out and tell me? Anything will help to improve proof writing ability. Thanks in advance.

Proof. $(\rightarrow)$ Suppose $x\in f^{-1}(Y \texttt{\\}Z)$ and $x\in A$ is arbitrary element of $f^{-1}(Y \texttt{\\}Z)$. Then there's a y$\in Y \texttt{\\}Z$ such that $f^{-1} (y)=x$. It follows that $y\in Y$ and $y\notin Z $. So $\exists x\in A$ such that $x=f^{-1}(y)$, where $y\in Y$ and $\neg \exists x\in A $ s.t. $x=f^{-1}(z)$, where $z\in Z$. Thus $x\in f^{-1}(Y)$ and $x\notin f^{-1}(Z)$. Therefore $x\in f^{-1}(Y) \texttt{\\} f^{-1}(Z)$. Since x was arbitrary we reach the conclusion that $f^{-1}(Y \texttt{\\}Z) \subseteq f^{-1}(Y) \texttt{\\} f^{-1}(Z)$.

(On the opposite direction we want to show that $x\in f^{-1}(Y \texttt{\\}Z)$, while for some $y\in B$, $y\in Y$ and $y\notin Z$.)

$(\leftarrow)$ Suppose $x\in f^{-1}(Y) \texttt{\\} f^{-1}(Z)$ and $y,z$ arbitrary elements of $B$. So $x\in f^{-1}(Y)$ and $x\notin f^{-1}(Z)$. So $\exists y \in Y$ s.t. $x=f^{-1}(y)$ and $\neg \exists z(z \in Z) =\forall z(z\notin Z)$ s.t. $x=f^{-1}(z)$. So $x=f^{-1}(y)\neq f^{-1}(z) \iff f^{-1}(y)\neq f^{-1}(z)$. But since $f$ is clearly revertible, as given, both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are one-to-one and onto. Following from $f^{-1}(y)\neq f^{-1}(z)$ we have that $y\neq z$. So $x=f^{-1}(y)$ and $y\in Y \texttt{\\}Z$, hence $x\in f^{-1}(Y \texttt{\\}Z)$. Since $x$ was arbitrary we've reached that $f^{-1}(Y) \texttt{\\} f^{-1}(Z) \subseteq f^{-1}(Y \texttt{\\}Z)$.

From $(\rightarrow)$ and $(\leftarrow)$ we can conclude that the statement $f^{-1}(Y \texttt{\\}Z)=f^{-1}(Y) \texttt{\\} f^{-1}(Z)$ will always be true.

Comment: Take car here... If $f$ is not a bijection, you can't speak of the map$f^{-1}$. $f^{-1}(Y)$ is the inverse image. Not the image of $Y$ under $f^{-1}$. Again $f^{-1}$ might not exist.

Comment: How can $f$ not be invertible? Since the inverse of $f$ is given then i conclude that $f$ is a bijection. Where is the mistake in my argument?

Comment: @RestlessC0bra: $f^{-1}(Y)$ (as I know it) is defined as the *set* of all $x$ such that $f(x) \in Y$. This does not require that $f$ is invertible. Example: $f(x) = x^2$, $f^{-1}(\{1 \}) = \{ -1,1 \}$.

Comment: You never stated that an inverse for f was given. We use the notation $f^{-1}(Y)$ for the set $ \{ x \in A \,\lvert f(x) \in Y\}$, and it does not imply that f is invertible.

Comment: $f^{-1}(Y)$ is sadly a misleading notation. $f^{-1}(Y)=\{x \in A \ : \ f(x) \in Y\}$ is the inverse image of $Y$ under $f$. Not the direct image of $Y$ under $f^{-1}$.

Comment: I see. But, this notation does imply that $f$ is invertible within those sets $Y$ and $Z$, which are subsets of $B$ right?

Comment: It does not imply that. See Martin R's example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement $f^{-1}(Y \setminus Z)=f^{-1}(Y) \setminus f^{-1}(Z)$
is correct, but your proof is problematic. For example, as already mentioned in
a comment, $f$ need not be invertible, and then equations like
$x=f^{-1}(y)$ make no sense.

But you can proceed as follows
(using the definition $f^{-1}(W)=\{x \in A \ : \ f(x) \in W\}$):
$$
\begin{aligned}
x \in f^{-1}(Y \setminus Z) &\Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in Y \setminus Z \\
&\Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in Y \text { and } f(x) \notin Z \\
&\Longleftrightarrow x \in f^{-1}(Y) \text { and } x \notin f^{-1}(Z) \\
&\Longleftrightarrow x \in f^{-1}(Y) \setminus f^{-1}(Z)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Yes by using the definition it's very clear indeed. Thanks. But, i'm concerned about the logic setting in my proof. Suppose $f$ is invertible as i thought. Will then my proof be correct? If not do you have a few key things to point out to me for proofs?

Comment: @RestlessC0bra: Even then your proof is unclear (to me). You start with "Suppose $x\in f^{-1}(Y \setminus Z)$ ...". Later: "$\exists x\in A$ such that ..." and "$\neg \exists x\in A $ s.t. ...". How are these $x$ related? You have to consider *one* $x$ which is element of the set on left-hand side and then show that it is also contained in the set on the right-hand side.

Comment: You're saying that i took for granted that these two $x$ are equal and i shouldn't have?

Comment: I am just saying that it is unclear.